# How to insert into existing table column value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am VERY new to SQL and I am having a little trouble.

Let's say I have a table, called **data**, with two columns, `class`, and `name`.

I want to create the column `math` if it doesn't exist, and give it a value of `John`.

I can do this with:

```
 INSERT INTO data VALUES ('math','John')
```

But if I change `John` to `Steve`, I want `math` to have a value of `"John","Steve"`.

But instead, it creates another row called `"math"` with a value of `"Steve"`, how can I make this insert into the same column?

Thanks

Comment: Please give sample data and expected output.

Comment: I did, sample data is a column named "math", with two values "John" and "Steve". Expected output is a single column named "math", with two values "John" and "Steve". But right now, it's created two columns both named "math", with values "John" and "Steve" respectively

Comment: Post what you want the actual table to look like after the insert.  Your description is unclear.

Comment: Don't store CSV in a column; it invites problems.

Comment: I don't see the confusion. I want the table to have 1 column, called "math" with two values.

Comment: Please give a clear sample data structure. Your description is not enough, we cant understand your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend *against* storing a CSV list of names in your table.  CSV is hard to query, update, and maintain.  Actually, there is nothing at all wrong with your current approach:

```
class | name
math  | John
math  | Steve
```

Data in this format can easily be queried, because it is relational.  And if you need to add, update, or remove a name associated with a class, it becomes a one record affair without having to deal with CSV.  Note that if you really need a CSV representation, you can still achieve that using SQLite's [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat) function:

```
SELECT class, GROUP_CONCAT(name, ',') AS names
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY class
```

Comment: This returns everything separated by a ",", anyway to make it produce a list or tuple?

Comment: @Will Update your question to show what you mean by "list" or "tuple."

Comment: Sounds like Python: `list = [row[0] for row in c.execute("SELECT name FROM names WHERE class = 'math'")]`

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure about SQLite but the normal command usually is something like:

ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype

Then insert into